SSMTP using wrong configuration
I can't get SSMTP to work. It has worked until I changed to  a different mail provider. I modified /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf to use the new mail server and port, but ssmtp still uses the old configuration. I can tell because if I do
echo -e "Subject: test\n\nTesting ssmtp" | ssmtp -v recipient@example.com

the command times out with ssmtp: Cannot open [old mail server]:[old mail port].
I tried to force using the config file with the -C/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf flag, but that didn't make any difference.
Short of grepping my whole disk for the old server name and port, what can I do to troubleshoot this?
I'm on Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS. /usr/sbin/ssmtp is the executable. SSMTP version is 2.64. ("Not sendmail at all"). /usr/sbin/sendmail is linked to this executable.

I have in fact done a grep for the old mail server, starting with /etc, and the culprit was soon found. I use revaliases ("reverse aliases") where you link a Linux user name to a mail address and server. There I found the old mail server mentioned next to recipient@example.com. The file is /etc/ssmtp/revaliases.
Though this may be slightly obvious, I leave this here for anyone having the same problem.
